# How to use a layout file inside a plugin in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7*

I have created a plugin which works correctly. However, the layout file it is using is the default one inside `app/View/Layouts`. How do I make it use the default layout I place inside `plugins/MyPlugin/View/Layouts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use it like PluginName.layoutName

For example,

```
$this->layout = "MyPlugin.mylayout";
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)
Is it bad practice to put this in the `beforeFIlter` method of my plugin's `MyPluginAppController` or is that the best place for it?